# How to use a discord.py bot that gives a user role when they join VC and remove it when they leave

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make a discord bot that gives a user role when they join a voice channel and removes the role when they leave it. I know about on_voice_state_update and how to give a user a role but I don't know how to get what user joined the channel to give them the role.

Right now my code is slightly modified version of the answer from 
[How to use discord.py event handler on_voice_state_update to run only when a user joins a voice channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50477079/how-to-use-discord-py-event-handler-on-voice-state-update-to-run-only-when-a-use).

```
@client.event
async def on_voice_state_update(before, after ):
    if before.voice.voice_channel is None and after.voice.voice_channel is not None:
        for channel in before.server.channels:
            if channel.name == 'general':
                await client.send_message(channel, "User joined")
```

`elif before.voice.voice_channel is not None and after.voice.voice_channel is None:
    for channel in before.server.channels:
        if channel.name == 'general':
            await client.send_message(channel, "User left");`

Answer (score 4):

Three months late, but for anyone who stumbles upon this later, here's the rewite (1.0) branch version.

```py
# VC PROCESSING
@client.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):
    if not before.channel and after.channel:
        role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, name="role name")
        await member.add_roles(role)
    elif before.channel and not after.channel:
        role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, name="role name")
        await member.remove_roles(role)
```

Answer (score 0):

`after` is the `Member` object as it exists "now", after the voice state has changed. That would be the member object that you pass to [`add_roles`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.add_roles)

```
@client.event
async def on_voice_state_update(before, after ):
    role = discord.utils.get(after.server.roles, name="YOUR ROLE NAME")
    if not before.voice.voice_channel and after.voice.voice_channel:
        await client.add_roles(after, role)
    elif before.voice.voice_channel and not after.voice.voice_channel:
        await client.remove_roles(after, role)
```