# discord py : AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'members'

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

i have an error in my code, it's a discord py command for my bot. The command is working anyways but i would like to understand... it's pretty ugly in my Terminal :P

code :

```
@bot.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):
    if len(after.channel.members) == 1:     # Must be set to 10 when the bot is ready
        if after.channel.category.name[:5] == "Lobby":
            for text_channel in after.channel.category.text_channels:
                for member in after.channel.members:
                    await text_channel.set_permissions(member, view_channel = True)
            for voice_channel in after.channel.category.voice_channels:
                for member in after.channel.members:
                    await voice_channel.set_permissions(member, connect = True)
```

error :

```
Ignoring exception in on_voice_state_update
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mattm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\mattm\Desktop\botdiscord\MMR6\main.py", line 88, in on_voice_state_update
    if len(after.channel.members) == 1:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'members'
True
Ignoring exception in on_voice_state_update
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mattm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\mattm\Desktop\botdiscord\MMR6\main.py", line 88, in on_voice_state_update
    if len(after.channel.members) == 1:         # Must be set to 10 when the bot is ready
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'members'
```

Comment: Check out this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50477079/how-to-use-discord-py-event-handler-on-voice-state-update-to-run-only-when-a-use. You have to use *after* a little bit differently.

Comment: You can't use it in after because `VoiceState.channel` will be `None` after they leave. https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=voice_state#discord.VoiceState.channel - you'll have to use `before.channel`.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what the user does, `before.channel` or `after.channel` could be `None`.

1. If the user moves between two channels, `before.channel` will be the one they were in before, and then `after.channel` is the one that they are in now.
2. If the user joins the channel, then they previously were not in a channel, so the channel they joined is in `after`.
3. Finally, if the user leaves, then they are no longer in a channel now, so the channel they previously were in is in `before`.

```py
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):
    if before.channel is None:
        # do things when they join
        print(f'they joined {after.channel.name}')
    elif after.channel is None:
        # do things when they leave
        print(f'they left {before.channel.name}')
    else:
        # do things when they move
        print(f'they moved from {before.channel.name} to {after.channel.name}')
```

Output could look like this:

```
they joined General
they left General
they joined General
they moved from General to Music
they moved from Music to General
they moved from General to Event
they left Event
```

Comment: Yes but my after is not None, cuz the user join the channel no ?

Comment: Voice update is called when they leave as well. You have to check that they joined (before is none), and then you can look at `after.channel`.